Reading doubles (numbers) in and out of Excel cells
I'm reading in values from an Excel sheet and have the user checking those numbers/text and hitting save again if they are correct. It works well for any text and numbers, except for my discount being of double type.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' filling form
TextHN.Text = Range("D3")
'...
' original: TextDP.Text = Range("D7") - but wouldn't read in 12.5
' therefore tried below as well
 Dim new_value As Double
    If IsNumeric(Range("D7").Value) Then
        new_value = CDbl(Range("D7").Value)
        MsgBox new_value # displays 12.5
        Else
        new_value = 1
    End If
    TextDP.Text = CStr(CDbl(new_value))
    MsgBox TextDP.Text # displays 12


I read several articles (Convert TextBox.Value to Double into VBA (Excel 2013) & https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/textbox-value-to-double.1066876/), but nothing helped.
How do I need to change my code to display my discount in TextDP? (I can read it out as double into Excel file fine)
Update with screenshots:


I'm surprised that it displays it for hospital name and abbreviation correctly (and saves it accordingly), but not for discount percentage and expiry length...

You convert the input into a double with new_value = CDbl(Range("D7").Value). It displays the proper content. Why are you then trying to make it a double again and then convert it to a string with TextDP.Text = CStr(CDbl(new_value)) when it's already a double? You don't need the second call to CDbl before you use CStr - just use CStr(new_value).

I did not find any problem when solving it as your first line. It works (on excel 2016). How do you interface with your sheet from VBA user form?
I think, there are something wrong in your sheet text/formatting.

@KenWhite: I removed the second CDbl - but have no luck since it still displays 12 in the second MsgBox.

@AbuBenReaz: I'm using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20030) 64-bit; if there is something else wrong - what should I check for?

TextDP is a cell.,Tou need to check to see what the formatting is for that cell. Make sure it's Number and not Integer. You're accessing .Text, which would be what is displayed, so if you have it set to integer formatting, you'll get that integer representation.

@KenWhite: TextDP is actually a TextBox I've created on my UserForm - sorry if that wasn't clear beforehand. Can I change the formatting to Integer? (I can't see it listed in the property window) I've tried TextDP.Value, but still same outcome.

Read this: https://oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/default.htm it will help you understand how Excel and VBA interface with regards to international settings such as decimal separators.

A couple of pointers.  1.  You are using unqualified Ranges.  You should always qualify the range statement with at least a worksheet reference.  2.  You are requesting the DefaultMember value from the Range.  You should always be specific about exactly what you want from the range.  In this case I'd suggest .it might be value2.   If you are requesting .Text, then you need to check the formatting applied to Cell D7 as indicated by @KenWhite

What is the problem you've created for yourself? TextHN.Text = Range("D3") works with any value in the cell.

What happens in TextDP.Text = Range("D7") if "D7" is 12.5?

What does % mean in the code? The comment sign is #.

I promise to upvote your question if you share the way how to get TextHN.Text = Range("D3") refuses to work.

@rotabor: I'm sorry about % - I'm simultaneous writing in Tex and that it's their comment. # --> learnt something new. Regarding TextDP.Text = Range("D7") and "D7" is 12.50, my UserForm only shows 12. (And if I don't change it back, saves 12.00 into "D7"); TextHN.Text = Range("D3") works fine since it is text (there is data from line "D1" to "D18" which I read into the UserForm.)

What is 12.50 in D7? Is it a number? Test it in another cell =ISNUMBER(D7). Why does it have two digits after the dot? What is the number format of D7? What is the value of the MaxLength property of  TextDP?

@rotabor: I declared D7 as Number (changed it from General after the double problem) with two digits since I thought it might make a difference. =ISNUMBER(D7) provides TRUE. MaxLength is set to  (default) '0'

@freeflow: I've now tried CDec(Range("D7").Value) as well as CDec(Range("D7").Value2), but both still display 12 in second MsgBox

@jkpieterse: I read your link and tried several versions, including TextDP.NumberFormat = "0.00", Range("D7").NumberFormat = "0.00", TextDP.Text = Format(Range("D7")) and TextDP.Value = Format(Range("D7").Value2) - nothing worked to display 12.5

I don't see available the NumberFormat property of the TextBox control of Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library which is used with Excel. Where have you got this control from? Can you test TextHN.Text = 12.5 and TextDP.Text = 12.5? Can you recreate TextDP? Can you share your workbook somewhere? Or can you depict the VBA window with the UserForm and TextDP selected?

I would like to explain what going on in TextDP.Text = Range("D7"). The value of D7 (the number as is, cell formatting doesn't affect) converts to a text and assigns to 'TextDP.Text'. The only limit here is TextBox.MaxLength (standard Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library TextBox control).

I guess SpinButtons affect that TextBoxes. Disable the code related to SpinButtons. I suspected something like this.

SpinButton works with integer. How do you plan to work with a fractional number?

@ChrisPeh It would be very useful if we could have a look at your file. Apparently there is more going on than we can see.

Evidently, SpinButton's or else code affects TextBox's content.
Highly likely, the TextDP_Change event is handled to setup related SpinButton. Then SpinButton_Change sets TextDP back.

By deleting the SpinButton, the problem solved and I can simply reflect value from cell by TextDP.Text = Range("D7").
